# Set-Builder Notation Where Numbers Increase With Fixed Value

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a little shaky with set-builder notation and I was wondering how to define the following range mathematically: $[0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15]$

I understand that, for instance, $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0.05 \leq x \leq 0.15\}$ specifies that the variable $x$ is any real number between $0.05 $ and $0.015$, but how would I write, in set-builder notation, that the variable $x$ is limited by $0.05$ and $0.15$ but only includes those numbers at intervals of $0.025$?

In the proposed notation, I want to make clear that the value $x$ lies between the range of $0.05$ and $0.15$ and that the values that belong in $x$ are only those values which are increments of $0.025$.

Comment: But there are only five numbers! List them.

Comment: What about $ \{ 0.025 n | n \in \mathbb Z , 2 \le n \le 6 \} $?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not entirely sure what you mean, this is the range that I want to encapsulate. Beginning at 0.05 and increasing at 0.025 increments until the limit of 0.15.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Is it at all possible to reformulate this by making the limits clearer? I'm not sure this is what I want to convey.

Comment: By "limits" do you mean $0.05$ (the least number in the list) and $0.15$ (the greatest number in the list)? Or something else? And if there is something specific that you want to convey, it's better that you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4271298/edit) your post and add some explanation. As it stands, the suggestions by @MauroALLEGRANZA and myself seem to be perfect suggestions.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly, I hope it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- Write $[0.05, 0.15] \cap 0.025 \mathbb Z$. *(The intersection of $[0.05,0.15]$, the interval of *all* real numbers in this range, with $0.025\mathbb Z$, the set of all integer multiples of $0.025$.)*
- Write $\{x \in \mathbb R : 0.05 \le x \le 0.15 \text{ and } \frac{x}{0.025} \in \mathbb Z\}$. *(The restriction that $\frac{x}{0.025}$ is an integer also implies that $x$ is a multiple of $0.025$. We could simplify this to $40x \in \mathbb Z$, but then it's not immediately clear that the step size is $0.025$.)*
- Write $\{0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15\}$. *(This is the best way when the set is not too large. But you wouldn't want to do this if we were going from $1$ to $100$ in increments of $0.025$.)*
- Write a description in words like "the set of numbers starting at $0.05$ and going up by $0.025$ until reaching $0.15$". *(The first goal of mathematical notation is being understood. Often the best way to do this is with words, not symbols.)*

The first two methods rely on the fact that the starting point $0.05$ is a multiple of $0.025$. If we wanted to go from $0.05$ to $0.15$ in multiples of $0.02$, we'd need a more careful restriction, such as
$$
   \{x \in \mathbb R: 0.05 \le x \le 0.15 \text{ and } \tfrac{x-0.05}{0.02} \in \mathbb Z\}.
$$

Comment: Thanks very much, I think the first choice is the neatest out of those proposed and meets the conditions outlined (in that all of them are multiples of 0.025).

Comment: @AlexanderHepburn Yet (as is mentioned in the last paragraph of the post) it has the disadvantage that you need to verify $ 0.05 \in 0.025 \mathbb Z $ and $ 0.15 \in 0.025 \mathbb Z $ to see that those are indeed the "limits". For example, $ [ 0.04 , 0.16 ] \cap 0.025 \mathbb Z $ indicates the same set, while $ 0.04 $ and $ 0.16 $ are virtually irrelevant.